# PHP Find text pattern

Tags: php, match

How can I find a 3 character text pattern in a string of: 
an upper or lowercase alphabetic character (a to z or A to Z) followed by
a numeric character (0 to 9) followed by
an upper or lowercase alphabetic character (a to z or A to Z)

for example x4A or A3j or A7X or h1k

Comment: I looked and those pattern matches did not fit my requirement. I also know I could loop through testing but that is pretty inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/[a-z]\d[a-z]/i', $my_string, $matches);
// now $matches contains all you want
```

Comment: read [docs on preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use

```
/[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]/
```

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9][a-zA-Z]{1}
```

demo : http://regexr.com?3199m

Comment: I tested this and iax87e5 returned true when it should be false

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}/',$string,$matches);
```

`$matches` now contains all your matches.

Comment: I tested this and iax87e5 returned true when it should be false